# Python subclass list of generic type T

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, generics, subclass

I'm trying to subclass `list` of generic type `T`. Right now, I'm able to achieve what I want with multiple inheritance with `Generic` and `list` as shown below. Is there a better way to achieve the same?

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class SuperList(Generic[T], list):
    def __init__(self, *args: T):
        super().__init__(args)
 
    def really_awesome_method(self):
        ...

class A(SuperList[int]):
    pass

class B(SuperList[str]):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's new in 3.9, but you can subscript many builtin containers to create generic type aliases. So you should be able to just do:

```
class SuperList(list[T]):
    def __init__(self, *args: T):
        super().__init__(args)

class A(SuperList[int]):
    pass
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias

Comment: very cool, looks like can also use `List[T]` for 3.7.